# Locate Blow-up in NDSolve with Whenevent

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

At some point I get this error:

```
Warning: scaled local spatial error estimate of 32773.0090044258` at 
t = 987.7919550194803` in the direction of independent variable x is much greater than the     
prescribed error tolerance. Grid spacing with 1001 points may be too large to achieve the  
desired accuracy or precision.
```

(etc.)

How do I track this time with `WhenEvent`? How is this *scaled local spatial error* kept in NDSolve?

Comment: See https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolvePDE.html#2081642391